# Several packages conflicting with graphicx

Tags: graphics, xetex, incompatibility, books

I am trying to typeset an English book class document using xelatex so that I can use the fonts in my system. I find that several packages conflict with graphicx, such as wrapfig, afterpage and url. I just wondered if this is normal or I need to update my installation or something. If I have to live with it, can I use the features these packages provide without using them?

Comment: This is not normal. can you add some example document that reproduces your problems?

Comment: None of those packages normally conflict with graphicx, so as lulu mentions, please provide example code that is (1) complete and thus ought to work, but does not at your end.

Comment: I suggest that you *first* update your system as it sound like something is very broken, that will avoid a lot of unnecessary work for you providing examples and for others to check them. These packages are fairly core and such problems are unheard of.

Comment: Guess it is better that I update the packages and check again. I shall report here after that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the options dvips,xetex I had given to graphicx was the culprit. The problem went away when I moved the options to the documentclass command. The help option in the command line gave the solution, which I should have checked earlier. It usually doesn't give much help, which is why I don't try it normally. Sorry for the time you had to spend reading my question and suggesting steps.

Comment: `dvips` and `xetex` are mutually exclusive options. They target different backends (command-line programmes) for PDF generation from  intermediate DVI, `dvips` and `xdvipdfmx`. As you are using `xelatex`, remove both options completely. The correct backend driver is automatically detected.